# how to make column width adjust automatically as per the data inside in Datatable

Tags: css, angularjs, laravel, datatable

I am creating datatable as this :

```
var Master = $('#MasterGrid').DataTable( {
            "data": response,   
            "columns":columns,
            "scrollX": true,                            
            });
        $('#MasterGrid').show();
```

[picture displaying row design is distorted completely as the height of the row is increased because of column string length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4G6d.png)

my table rows height got irregular just because of this issue i am trying to make column width adjustable according to the dynamic data that is being filled in the column.
i ve tried using :

```
 columnDefs: [
        { width: 200, targets: 0 }
    ],
```

and

```
scroller: {
    rowHeight: 30
}
```

by using scroller it is distorting my table style [picture displaying the distortion in the datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOmvg.png)

I have tried using but nothing seems taking effect on the table

```
$('#masterGrid').column.adjust().draw();
```

Comment: now after getting it solved i cam accross this issue and nothing seems to be working here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819900/datatables-table-header-column-data-misaligned-when-using-sscrolly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution of the issue applying following steps.
1) Irregular height issue of row fixed by adding this css.

```
th, td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

2)  table headers column and body column misalignment issue solved when I removed scrollx

```
var Master = $('#MasterGrid').DataTable( {
    "data": response,   
    "columns":columns,
});

$('#MasterGrid').show();
$('#MasterGrid').wrap("<div class='scrolledTable'></div>");
```

3) adding custom css in the style.css file

```
.scrolledTable{ overflow-x: auto; clear:both; }
```

@Syed Ali Taqi thanks for your help sir!
this solve the question with this link too [Datatables table header & column data misaligned when using "sScrollY"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819900/datatables-table-header-column-data-misaligned-when-using-sscrolly)

Answer (score 1):

Try this `CSS`:

```
th, td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Working **[Demo](http://output.jsbin.com/focoyijopu)**

Comment: sir it worked but its still not matching with the table header pls see the pic here   https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM1up.png

Comment: can you reproduce the problem is demo link? I tried with a long header value it is working fine.

Comment: now i got this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819900/datatables-table-header-column-data-misaligned-when-using-sscrolly

Comment: did you try the fixes in link?